# Как добавить новый объект в массив объекта?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
 let menu = {
        products: [
          {name: 'Stripsy', price: 22},
          {name: 'Gamburger', price: 17},
          {name: 'Chicken', price: 21}
        ],
        orders: [
            {count: 1, name: 'Stripsy1', price: 22 },
            {count: 1, name: 'Gamburger2', price: 17},
            {count: 1, name: 'Chicken', price: 21}
        ]
    };


    function func1() {
        for (let i = 0; i < menu.products.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < menu.orders.length; j++) {
                if (menu.products[i] === menu.orders[j]) {
                    menu.orders[j].count += 1;
                    return;
                } else {
                   menu.orders[j].push(menu.products[i]);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: А можно чуточку деталей? Пока не понятно, что у Вас не так. Но могу предложить метод `concat` для добавления нового элемента в массив, через конкатенацию массива без его изменения, либо через spread syntax (три точки), либо может подойдет `push` метод... Пока не понятно что и куда Вам не удается добавить.

Comment: Изначально menu.orders это пустой массив. Я хочу по клику добавить элемент массива из menu.products в массив menu.orders и проверить если такой массив который я пытаюсь добавить в массив orders уже существует тогда просто изменить count этого массива на +1. если нет то добавить этот элемент в массив orders

Comment: О стороне клиента. Экран разделен на две части в левом выводится на экран Продукты а в правом Заказы.

Comment: Так, задачу примерно понял, а что не работает? Что Вы ожидаете и что в результате? Добавленные комментарии по-хорошему бы перенести в вопрос, и дополнить его конкретной проблемой, которая у Вас возникает.

Comment: Не работает функция(именно эта функция) по клику! Я динамически вывожу на экран массив продуктов и плюс добавляю кнопки + (для первого раза: добавляет этот продукт в массив заказов (и для заказов тоже сделал динамический вывод на экран по перебору массива orders) а когда уже второй клик он просто будет увеличивать кол-во продукта на единицу ) вторая кнопка минус работает аналогичном образом в обратную сторону и когда кол-во заказа будет равняться единице и будет еще нажата кнопка минус заказ удаляется из массива тем же временем и с экрана!

Comment: здесь мой код точно не показывает то что я хочу делать! Это только для построения логики!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так если правильно понял из Ваших комментариев! (upd чуть подправил код, удалил лишнее)

```js
let menu = {
    products: [
      {name: 'Stripsy', price: 22},
      {name: 'Gamburger', price: 17},
      {name: 'Chicken', price: 21}
    ],
    orders: []
};
const contProduct = document.querySelector('.items-product');    
const contOrders = document.querySelector('.items-order');
function showProducts() {
  contProduct.innerHTML = '';
  menu.products.map((item, index) => {
    contProduct.innerHTML +='<div data-id="'+ index +'" class="item-product">' + item.name + '</div>'; 
  });
}
showProducts();

function showOrders() {
  contOrders.innerHTML = '';
  menu.orders.map((item, index) => {
    contOrders.innerHTML +='<div class="item-order">' + item.name + ' ' + item.count + '</div>'; 
  });
}

const itemsProduct = document.querySelectorAll('.item-product');
itemsProduct.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const itemProduct = menu.products[parseInt(e.target.dataset.id)];
    const haveOrder = menu.orders.some((itemOrder) => {
        
    if (itemOrder.name === itemProduct.name) {
        itemOrder.count += 1;
        return true;
    }
       return false;
    });
    if (!haveOrder) {
      itemProduct.count = 1;
      menu.orders.push(itemProduct);
    }
    showOrders();
  })
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items-product">
  
  </div>
  <div class="items-order">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я очень вам благодарен. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @SaidbekAhmadbekov пожалуйста =)